# PHP: How to send GCM notification to multiple devices at one post

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm an android developer and currently working on GCM server side using PHP. From my client side I'm storing the gcm response token in one database, and now I want to send message to the registered users, at one go. I'm not able to figure out how to do that, and I'm totally confused. My simple HTML file is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
GCM
</title>
</head>
<body topmargin="50" leftmargin="50" CLASS = "bg">
<form action="send_message.php" name="myform" method="post">
<h4>Admin for sending notificaion to the registered user</h4>
Notification Text: <input name="appText" size="15" type="text"/><br>
URL: <input name="url" size="15" type="text" /><br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And, my send_message.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting (0);

$link = mysql_connect("localhost","db","db"); 
if (!$link) 
 { 
 die(mysql_error()) ; 
 } 
mysql_select_db("gcm_user")or die(mysql_error());
........................................
.....................................
.....................................
?>
```

Now, in the php file what should I do, I have tried this link [Android Hive example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Just, now came through this link. Please suggest me how to use this solution for my problem. [New link for my problem.](http://labs.distriqt.com/post/1273)

But I want only one php for my purpose. Please help in overcoming this prm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question. Here is what I have done to meet my requirements.

```
$gcm_text = $_POST['gcmText'];
$gcm_url = $_POST['gcmURL'];
$gcm_subText = $_POST['gcm_secondText'];

$sql = "select gcm_response_token as regId from GCM";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $gcm_array[]=$row['regId'];
    $counter++;
}

mysql_free_result($result);


    $body['allsearch'] = array(
            'gcmText' => $gcm_text,
            'gcm_secondText' => $gcm_subText,
            'gcmURL' => $gcm_url
            );

    // Set POST variables
  $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

  $fields = array(
 'registration_ids' => $gcm_array,
 'data' => $body,
 );

//echo GOOGLE_API_KEY;
 $headers = array(
 'Authorization: key=$apiKey',
  'Content-Type: application/json'
 );


print_r($headers);
// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}

// Close connection
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;

?>
```

By this, I was able to send json data to the client side and get the notification.

Comment: i'm facing a strange issue, i have 3 devices, but receiving only in 1 device, other device status shows success nd devices r connected to internet as well, though not received.. my code works fine I hope as it works for one device, any clue why not receiving on other two devices?

Comment: Try this example for making server. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Where should I set the TTL value ?

Answer (score 2):

Those links seem to make the PHP over complicated. All you want to do is fill that $registrationIDs array with values from a query. I'm no PHP expert, but I used the often quoted CURL example and prepared statements like:

```
   $ttl = 86400;
   $randomNum=rand(10,100); 
   $registrationIDs = array();
   .....

   $queryregid = "select regid from registrations where  YOUR SPECIFIC CRITERIA......";
   if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare( $queryregid))) {
      echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error; }
   if (!$stmt->execute()) {  
      echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error; }
   if (!$stmt->bind_result($dev_i)){  
      echo "bind failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;  }

   /* fetch values */
   while ($stmt->fetch()) {
      $regidOne =  $dev_i;
      $registrationIDs[] = $regidOne; // Fill the array
   }
   $stmt->close();

   $fields = array(
           'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
             'data' => array( "message" => $message),
             'delay_while_idle'=> false,
             'time_to_live' => $ttl,
             'collapse_key'=>"".$randomNum.""
            );
   $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
         'Content-Type: application/json'
         );

   // Open connection
   $ch = curl_init();

   // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ));

   // Execute post
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   // Close connection
   curl_close($ch);
```

.

Comment: Can you get me the things more clearly. I'm a PHP rookie guy, can't figure out the way to do that. Do you have any simple example for meeting my requirement.