# Sending Push Notification on multiple devices

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to make an push notification on my android app by following this tutorial

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

I already got this tutorial working, but my problem is. It only send notification one by one. I need to send the notification to all gcm_id or registered id by just sending once.

Do anyone already solved this issue?

here is my index.php

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

            });
            function sendPushNotification(id){
                var data = $('form#'+id).serialize();
                $('form#'+id).unbind('submit');                
                $.ajax({
                    url: "send_message.php",
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: data,
                    beforeSend: function() {

                    },
                    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                          $('.txt_message').val("");
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .container{
                width: 950px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 0;
            }
            h1{
                font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 24px;
                color: #777;
            }
            div.clear{
                clear: both;
            }
            ul.devices{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            ul.devices li{
                float: left;
                list-style: none;
                border: 1px solid #dedede;
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 0 15px 25px 0;
                border-radius: 3px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
                font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                color: #555;
            }
            ul.devices li label, ul.devices li span{
                font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-style: normal;
                font-variant: normal;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #393939;
                display: block;
                float: left;
            }
            ul.devices li label{
                height: 25px;
                width: 50px;                
            }
            ul.devices li textarea{
                float: left;
                resize: none;
            }
            ul.devices li .send_btn{
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0096FF), to(#005DFF));
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0096FF), to(#005DFF));
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #0096FF, #005DFF);
                background: linear-gradient(#0096FF, #005DFF);
                text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                border-radius: 3px;
                color: #fff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include_once 'db_functions.php';
        $db = new DB_Functions();
        $users = $db->getAllUsers();
        if ($users != false)
            $no_of_users = mysql_num_rows($users);
        else
            $no_of_users = 0;
        ?>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>No of Devices Registered: <?php echo $no_of_users; ?></h1>
            <hr/>
            <ul class="devices">
                <?php
                if ($no_of_users > 0) {
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
                        ?>
                        <li>
                            <form id="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>" name="" method="post" onsubmit="return sendPushNotification('<?php echo $row["id"] ?>')">
                                <label>Name: </label> <span><?php echo $row["name"] ?></span>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <label>Email:</label> <span><?php echo $row["email"] ?></span>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <div class="send_container">                                
                                    <textarea rows="3" name="message" cols="25" class="txt_message" placeholder="Type message here"></textarea>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="regId" value="<?php echo $row["gcm_regid"] ?>"/>
                                    <input type="submit" class="send_btn" value="Send" onclick=""/>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    <?php }
                } else { ?> 
                    <li>
                        No Users Registered Yet!
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

send_message.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
if (isset($_GET["regId"]) && isset($_GET["message"])) {
    $regId = $_GET["regId"];
    $message = $_GET["message"];

    include_once './GCM.php';

    $gcm = new GCM();

    $registatoin_ids = array($regId);
    $message = array("price" => $message);

    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

    echo $result;
}
?>
```

GCM.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of GCM
 *
 * @author Ravi Tamada
 */
class GCM {

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {

    }

    /**
     * Sending Push Notification
     */
    public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
        // include config
        include_once './config.php';

        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not having exp in PHP but I can tell you the places where you can modify your code.

Make an array of ids and put into `registration_ids`.

At the end you must have all ids into `registatoin_ids` at

```
$fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids, // HERE IT IS
            'data' => $message,
        );
```

into `send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message)`.

In current it having single reg_id so it is sending notification to single device.

Comment: me either, I don't have exp using php. I already change this line multiple times but still not getting the right codes.

Comment: You can use `$registatoin_ids = array( "123", "456" );` show you code for static array... and u can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599110/php-how-to-send-gcm-notification-to-multiple-devices-at-one-post

Comment: I changed this codes to array and it works                      $registatoin_ids = array($regId);

Comment: Nice! I am happy to helped you... :)

Comment: who is Ravi Tamada? And what you are updating? @user1225296

Comment: I am the author of Androidhive.. I am saying I'll update the article by showing how to send notifications to multiple devices.. Anyway FYI this way of implementing Push notifications is deprecated. We need use Google Play Services now.

Comment: Yes you are right the way he is using is deprecated... And would happy to see your update as link here.. or I will update the answer when you will add your page to Androidhive.... But you should change your SO profile name...