# Google Cloud Messaging: Send message to "all" users

Tags: java, php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) to understand the system of GCM. I have a question regarding this part:

It is possible to send messages to every single registered user, but how to change that code so I can send a single message to ALL registered devices?

I've already looked for answers:

[sending push notifications to multiple android devices using GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859898/sending-push-notifications-to-multiple-android-devices-using-gcm)

and

[Sending Push Notification on multiple devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018027/sending-push-notification-on-multiple-devices)

(nearly same question) - but could not find any answer solving my question.

```
<body>
    <?php
    include_once 'db_functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $users = $db->getAllUsers();
    if ($users != false)
        $no_of_users = mysql_num_rows($users);
    else
        $no_of_users = 0;
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>No of Devices Registered: <?php echo $no_of_users; ?></h1>
        <hr/>
        <ul class="devices">
            <?php
            if ($no_of_users > 0) {
                ?>
                <?php
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <form id="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>" name="" method="post" onsubmit="return sendPushNotification('<?php echo $row["id"] ?>')">
                            <label>Name: </label> <span><?php echo $row["name"] ?></span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <label>Email:</label> <span><?php echo $row["email"] ?></span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="send_container">                                
                                <textarea rows="3" name="message" cols="25" class="txt_message" placeholder="Type message here"></textarea>
                                <input type="hidden" name="regId" value="<?php echo $row["gcm_regid"] ?>"/>
                                <input type="submit" class="send_btn" value="Send" onclick=""/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                <?php }
            } else { ?> 
                <li>
                    No Users Registered Yet!
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

i tried to change the code, but with my change it does not work..

I want to put all regID as array into sendPushNofiy...

```
<body>
    <?php
    include_once 'db_functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $users = $db->getAllUsers();
    if ($users != false)
        $no_of_users = mysql_num_rows($users);
    else
        $no_of_users = 0;
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>No of Devices Registered: <?php echo $no_of_users; ?></h1>
        <hr/>
        <ul class="devices">
            <?php
            if ($no_of_users > 0) {
                ?>
                <?php
                    <li>      
                        $rows = array();
                        while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($users))) {
                            $rows[] = $row['id'];
                        }
                        <form id="<?php echo $rows ?>" name="" method="post" onsubmit="return sendPushNotification('<?php echo $rows ?>')">
                            <label>Name: </label> <span><?php echo $row["name"] ?></span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <label>Email:</label> <span><?php echo $row["email"] ?></span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="send_container">                                
                                <textarea rows="3" name="message" cols="25" class="txt_message" placeholder="Type message here"></textarea>
                                <input type="hidden" name="regId" value="<?php echo $row["gcm_regid"] ?>"/>
                                <input type="submit" class="send_btn" value="Send" onclick=""/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                    <?php 
            } else { ?> 
                <li>
                    No Users Registered Yet!
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>


</body>
```

with this I can get all regids into the array rows... but how can i transfer the array into the form?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
    $rows[] = $row["gcm_regid"];
}
```

my problem is how to send my array "row" to send_message.php?

`$registatoin_ids = array($regId);` << it does already handles array, but my input works only with one value, i want to transfer array^^

EDIT:
send_message.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET["regId"]) && isset($_GET["message"])) {
    $regId = $_GET["regId"];
    $message = $_GET["message"];
    
    include_once './GCM.php';
    
    $gcm = new GCM();

    $registatoin_ids = array($regId);
    $message = array("price" => $message);

    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

    echo $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: Oyur code already knows how to send a message to one device (see your `onsubmit="return sendPushNotification(...`). The code behind this sendPushNotification method has to be executed for every registration id. I recommend to not do it in the JavaSript. Move the send loop to the PHP code, and as Eran explained do not send more than 1000 messages in one request.

Comment: yeah i know, it already sends one message to one device - but I want to send only ONE message to ALL devices registred^^... i think it's only some change of php code to handle that -

Comment: The Google server does not know which devices are registered with your back-end server, so you will always have to send individual messages, one per device, with identical content

Comment: yes I know, I think I am missunderstood:

What the code from:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

is doing is: looping threw all the user id's to show a form, for sending a message for every single regID.

i want to change that formular, that the formular does not get a single regID - it shall get an array of regID (all regID in table) - but i could not make that. See my Edit there is a send_message.php , that already can handles the regID as array - but the regID is still no array -

Answer (score 6):

It's your responsibility to maintain a list of the Registration IDs of all the registered users. There's no API call to send a message to all registered users. You can send to GCM server a request with up to 1000 Registration IDs. If you have more than 1000 registered users, you'll have to split them to multiple requests.

Comment: Hmm ok that's an aspect i did not thought about... ok but when I can split it, then there is no problem.. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["message"])) {
  include_once 'db_functions.php';
  $db = new DB_Functions();
  $users = $db->getAllUsers();
  $regIds = array();
  if ($users != false){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users)) {
        $regIds[] = $row["gcm_regid"];
    }
  }

  include_once './GCM.php';

  $gcm = new GCM();

  $registatoin_ids = $regIds;
  $message = "array("price" => $_GET["message"])";

  $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

  echo $result;
}
?>
```